# Error handling with gulp-notify and gulp-plumber

Tags: gulp

I want to display a notification when:
1. An error occurs
2. When the script was successfully executed

All notifications are actually working but the success notification is always displayed, even when there is an error.

How can I make sure the success notification is only displayed when no errors have occurred?

This is my current task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
   return gulp.src('assets/scss/global.scss')
       .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>")}))
       .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
       .pipe(autoprefixer())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
       .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
       .pipe(minifycss())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
       .pipe(notify({
           title: 'Gulp',
           subtitle: 'success',
           message: 'Sass task',
           sound: "Pop"
       }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and what worked for me was gulp-if and a custom error handler. Basically, I set `errorFree = false` when an error is thrown then at the end when it's time to show the success message I use `gulp-if` to determine if `notify()` gets called or not.

Working with your gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function(){

    var onError = function(err) {
        notify.onError({
                    title:    "Gulp",
                    subtitle: "Failure!",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>",
                    sound:    "Beep"
                })(err);

        this.emit('end');
    };

   return gulp.src('assets/scss/global.scss')
       .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
       .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
       .pipe(autoprefixer())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
       .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
       .pipe(minifycss())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
       .pipe(notify({ // Add gulpif here
           title: 'Gulp',
           subtitle: 'success',
           message: 'Sass task',
           sound: "Pop"
       }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

In my gulpfile I actually wrap each step in `gulp-if` so that the stream stops processing. (I haven't found a way to stop the stream without killing the process, which defeats the purpose of watch IMO.)

Comment: Doing some more work on this issue this morning I realized that my solution forgot to call `this.emit('end');` in the `onError` function. I've edited it to reflect this.

Comment: Did some more work on this as my original solution just didn't seem right. Turns out `this.emit('end')` was all that was needed. I've removed the `gulp-f` and (now) unnecessary variables and helper methods. My answer is now exactly how it is in my local gulpfile.js and works as desired (error notice on error, success message otherwise.)

Comment: Use "message:  err.toString()" and error message will be much more informative

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a very similar situation recently and the code **Jeffwa** 
provided helped me make it work; but I'm compiling and merging several files, and was having issues with the error and the "success" notification being fired.

In case someone else run into a similar situation the solution I found was creating a function on the **success** notification and there returning either false if there was an error or the information object. This is the code example.

```
gulp.task('themeCss', function() {

    var errorFree = true;

    var onError = function(err) {

        errorFree = false;

        var subtitle = "Error";
        var message = error.message;

        notify.onError({
            title:    "Gulp",
            subtitle: subtitle,
            message:  message,
            sound: false
        })(err);

        this.emit('end');
    };

    //themeCssFiles is an array with the css files to be compiled/merged.
    return gulp.src( themeCssFiles )
        .pipe( plumber({
            errorHandler: onError,
        }) )
        .pipe( gulpIf("*.scss", compass({
            config_file: './compass-config.rb',
            sass: 'scss',
            css: outputCSS + "/compass"
        }) ) )
        .pipe( concatCss('theme.css', {
            rebaseUrls: false
        } ) )
        .pipe( notify( function(f) {
            return errorFree ? {
                title: 'Gulp',
                subtitle: 'success',
                message: 'SCSS ready',
            }
            : false ;
        }))
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/css' ) );
});
```