# Gulp js error notification not showing source of error

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

Everything is setup and working to concatenate and compile my styles and scripts. When an error occurs `gulp-notify` and `gulp-plumber` throw the error up as a mac notification and in terminal, and gulp doesn't stop running - which is great :)

However, I'm finding that the script errors that are thrown up in terminal are always problems with the compiled file `script-dist.js` instead of the actual concatenated source file.

**Error**

```
gulp-notify: [JS Error] _PATH_/js/script-dist.js: Unexpected token keyword «var», expected punc «{»
Error in plugin 'gulp-uglify'
Message:
    _PATH_/js/script-dist.js: Unexpected token keyword «var», expected punc «{»
Details:
    fileName: _PATH_/js/script-dist.js
    lineNumber: 3
```

Notice how this doesn't tell me where the actual error is coming from (it should say it's in `_modal.js`, one of the concatenated files I deliberately created an error in.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var include = require('gulp-include');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// JS
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./js/script.js'])
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorScripts}))
        .pipe(concat('script-dist.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Styles
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task("styles", function(){
    return gulp.src("./ui/scss/styles.scss")
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorStyles}))
        .pipe(sass({style: "compressed", noCache: true}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./ui/css/"))
        .pipe(livereload());
});


// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Errors
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Styles
function errorStyles(error){
    notify.onError({title: "Sass Error", message: "", sound: "Sosumi"})(error); //Error Notification
    console.log(error.toString()); // Prints Error to Console
    this.emit("end");
};

// Scripts
function errorScripts(error){
    notify.onError({title: "JS Error", message: "", sound: "Sosumi"})(error); //Error Notification
    console.log(error.toString()); // Prints Error to Console
    this.emit("end");
};

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Watch & Reload
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('watch', function() {   
    gulp.watch('./ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(['./js/*.js', '!./js/script-dist.js'], ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);

livereload.listen();
task("styles", function(){
        return gulp.src("./ui/scss/styles.scss")
            .pipe(include())
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: errorStyles}))
            .pipe(sass({style: "compressed", noCache: true}))
            .pipe(minifycss())
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./ui/css/"))
            .pipe(livereload());
    });


    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    // Errors
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    // Styles
    function errorStyles(error){
        notify.onError({title: "Sass Error", message: "", sound: "Sosumi"})(error); //Error Notification
        console.log(error.toString()); // Prints Error to Console
        this.emit("end");
    };

    // Scripts
    function errorScripts(error){
        notify.onError({title: "JS Error", message: "", sound: "Sosumi"})(error); //Error Notification
        console.log(error.toString()); // Prints Error to Console
        this.emit("end");
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    // Watch & Reload
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    gulp.task('watch', function() {   
        gulp.watch('./ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
        gulp.watch(['./js/*.js', '!./js/script-dist.js'], ['scripts']);
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
    gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);

    livereload.listen();
```

Answer (score 0):

You `concat` before passing to `uglify`, so as far as Uglify is concerned, there's only a single file there. You may want to use e.g. a linter to pass over the files first, making sure they're right.

Alternatively, use [sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps), which tools may take advantage of to show the *original* file the error occurred in.

Comment: Ah right thank you, Félix. That makes sense. I'm just not sure exactly how to achieve this as my JS knowledge doesn't stretch that far :)

Comment: Fortunately, gulp has a bunch of [recipes](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes) that make it all a bit easier to get right :)